# Controls comes outside the flowLayoutPanel1 when adding controls dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, flowlayoutpanel

I am adding 8 panels to a "flowLayoutPanel1". It works fine.

The problem is that it comes 4 panels on the first"row" and then 4 panels on next "row".
The thing is that I have made the size of the "flowLayoutPanel1" to visually show 3 panels on each "row", - so in this case, half of the 4th panel on each row are not seen.

But if I add them in the designer manually, it do come 3 panels on each "row" which I want.

I wonder why this is happening when I add them dynamically with this code?

```
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear(); int count = 0;
                        for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < latestImageLIST.Count; i++)
                            {
                                //Now add all images as panels
                                String imagefile = latestImageLIST[i];
                                if (File.Exists(imagefile))
                                {
                                    Panel panel = new Panel(); count++;
                                    panel.Name = "thepanel" + count;
                                    panel.Size = new Size(284, 160);
                                    panel.Margin = new Padding(3);
                                    Image image = Image.FromFile(imagefile);
                                    panel.BackgroundImage = image;
                                    panel.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                                    panel.Tag = "thepanel" + count;
                                    panel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.panel216_Click);
                                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Possibly a different DPI or display scaling value on the desktop/target machine vs the designer/your machine.

Comment: Yes perheps it is this problem. Is it possible to prevent this by using any setting? It is strange that the layoutpanel don't automatically detect if something goes outside of view (Since no scrollbars is shown)

Comment: I hate flowlayoutPanels.  They have very limited use and I cannot find a way to do what is needed.  Instead I create a main Panel and then add Panels to the main panel.  So simply add 8 panels to the main panel and set the top, left, width, and height of the 8 panels to fill the main panel.

Comment: @jdweng That is a great idéa. I will actually go with that. That sounds as a very good solution. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What I usually do is create a MyPanel that inherits the Panel and add two properties : Row, Column.  So when I get an event (like click) I can find the row and column easily.

Comment: That was a good idéa, I will do something like that to make it easy to know what rows/columns that are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using TableLayoutPanel, which is an alternative to FlowLayoutPanel. You can first determine the row and column based on the number of images you need to load, then dynamically create a Panel through a loop and add it to the specified row and column.

```
        public void AddImages(int row, int col)
        {
            TableLayoutPanel tlp = new TableLayoutPanel();
            int prow = 100 / row, pcol = 100 / col;
            for(var i=0;i<row;i++)
            {
                tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, prow));
            }
            for(var i=0;i<col;i++)
            {
                tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, pcol));
            }
            //modify the add logic according to your requirement.
            tlp.Controls.Add(new Panel() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill }, 1, 1);  
            //todo...
            this.Controls.Add(tlp);         
        }
```